# Azure: Restore encrypted Linux data disk not working

Tags: linux, azure, backup, azure-cli

I am currently trying to restore an encrypted Ubuntu 16 VM having one OS disk and one Data disk. I followed all the steps described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-automation#create-a-vm-from-restored-disks using the "Managed, encrypted VMs (BEK and KEK)" part.

However, I can only restore the OS disk. The encrypted disk shows up fine including partition, but I cannot mount it as it shows `mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1`.

What is happening is, that the data disk is not formatted at all. Interestingly, also the bek volume is not mounted automatically. So my suspicion is that something went wrong with the encryption process. Also, `az vm encryption show` shows a completely empty output as if there would be no encryption.

I also tried different ways of e.g., using the template, re-doing the restore etc. Any ideas?

Comment: This would involve further deeper technical analysis to find out the root cause and would need sensitive information like the Subscription and Tenant details which should not be disclosed on the public forums. So, I would suggest you open a support ticket as described in this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) . The ticket will help you work closely with the support for speedy resolution.

Comment: Did you ever find resolution to this issue?  I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: @ammills01 Not really, I somehow managed to restore the data disk, but never the OS disk fully. I am currently still running backups on encrypted machines and hope that it will work better in future when I need it.

Comment: Thanks for the response @fsociety.  We have tried recovering an encrypted attached drive and it recovered the drive but we had 100% data loss, similar to your original post.  We ran lots of tests in our lab and had the same experience each time.  Since we're using RHEL we didn't mess with OS disk encryption, it's not supported.